# How to get correct control id when we have multiple instance of same user control in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control with 2 button(Button1, Button2) & 1 text box(TextBox1). 
On Button1 Clientclick, i try to get ControlID of button1.

In main page i have two instance of same user control. When click first user control button1 click i got the last user control id (here i have two control)

UserControl1.Button1click gives: MyUserControl2_Button1 (suppose to display MyUserControl1_Button1), please clarify where is the problem. 
I appreciate your help.
Thanks
[image]

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControlProject.UserControl.MyUserControl" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function button1client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>").id);
    }
    function button2client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("<%= Button2.ClientID %>").id);
    }
</script>

<table width="100" border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" align="right" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="button1client(this);return false;" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="button2client(this);return false;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

  
 MainPage.aspx
 
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUserControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserControlProject.TestUserControl" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/MyUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyUserControl" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        
        <div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="MyUserControl1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="MyUserControl2" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PageSource shows:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function button1client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl1_Button1").id);
    }
    function button2client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl1_Button2").id);
    }
</script>

<table width="100" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>
            <table width="100%" align="right">
   <tr>
    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="MyUserControl1$Button1" value="Button1" onclick="button1client(this);return false;" id="MyUserControl1_Button1" />
                        <input type="submit" name="MyUserControl1$Button2" value="Button2" onclick="button2client(this);return false;" id="MyUserControl1_Button2" />
                    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
        </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
            <input name="MyUserControl1$TextBox1" type="text" id="MyUserControl1_TextBox1" />
        </td>
 </tr>
</table>


                    </td>
                    <td>
                        



<script type="text/javascript">
    function button1client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl2_Button1").id);
    }
    function button2client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl2_Button2").id);
    }
</script>

<table width="100" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>
            <table width="100%" align="right">
   <tr>
    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="MyUserControl2$Button1" value="Button1" onclick="button1client(this);return false;" id="MyUserControl2_Button1" />
                        <input type="submit" name="MyUserControl2$Button2" value="Button2" onclick="button2client(this);return false;" id="MyUserControl2_Button2" />
                    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
        </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
            <input name="MyUserControl2$TextBox1" type="text" id="MyUserControl2_TextBox1" />
        </td>
 </tr>
</table>


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of hoisting. Basically thats the way javascript works.
To understand it better inspect the page source when you run it. I'll try my best to explain it here.

When you run your ASP.NET application it loads both the user controls (since you have them both in your main page).

Both controls have javascript methods with same name.

First Control Loads this:

```
function button1client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl1_Button1").id);
    }
function button2client(ctrl) {
        alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl1_Button2").id);
    }
```

Than second user control is loaded which have same function name.

```
function button1client(ctrl) {
            alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl2_Button1").id);
        }
function button2client(ctrl) {
            alert(document.getElementById("MyUserControl2_Button2").id);
        }
```

The Javascript as a result of hoisting overrides the old function. They don't exist anymore in the javascript context. Therefore when any button is clicked, the method from second control is called.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is what it happening. Any other way is to find the correct control id?

Comment: you can use jQuery:
`$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
alert($(this).id);
});`

Comment: Actually this
`$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added $('input[type=submit]').click(function () { alert($(this).attr('id')); });. First user control button works fine, but second user control button click is not. How to add clientid in javascript method? any possibility is there?

Answer (score 0):

@chrana solution will work smoothly.If you are ready to use jQuery in your page this solution will work too.

User control code

```
<table id="Table2" width="100%" align="right" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn").on("click", function () {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
```